# Set HTTP responseType as arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, typescript, jhipster, arraybuffer

I facing an error while building a jhipster project that says that I need to change the parameter `responseType` in a `get` request.

Here's the error:

> Argument of type '{ responseType: "arraybuffer"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>     Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
>       Type '"arraybuffer"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
>   Version: typescript 2.7.2

As you see `typescript` is telling me to change the value from `arraybuffer` to `json`, but I need to keep it as `arraybuffer` since I am dealing with a file and I fully aware that the `responseType` can be set to `arraybuffer`, `blob`, `json` or `text`.

Here's the code

```
showfile(file?: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(SERVER_API_URL + `leave/api/downloadFile/${file}`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.http.get<any>
```

Remove the any

Answer (score 1):

When I need to call an endpoint that is returning a file, I usually use the type `Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>`.

Try:

```
showfile(file?: any): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    return this.http.get(SERVER_API_URL + `leave/api/downloadFile/${file}`, { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

Comment: that returns **_Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'_**

Answer (score 0):

We use an ArrayBuffer for a **PDF** file; this pattern works for the GET verb:

```
return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
```

Some considerations:

1. If the url is an API endpoint that does not return a file stream (e.g. MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM), rather it responds with JSON output, you cannot use a mismatched responseType.
2. Typescript does not require an explicit return type: "If no parameter type is defined, TypeScript will default to using any, unless additional type information is available ...." see https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_functions.php
3. If your editor and/or npm build are throwing errors, you may need to create an object to contain the responseType, like this:

```
    let HTTPOptions:Object = {responseType: 'arraybuffer'};
    return this.http.get(url, HTTPOptions );
```

4. You may only require the  explicit response type with a POST request, like this:

```
    return this.http.post<ArrayBuffer>(url, requestBody, HTTPOptions );
```